# Keyboard specific problem with Ctrl, Shift and Alt

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I am using a Mancer Ghoul keyboard in my Ubuntu 22.10. Any time I press Alt, Shift and Ctrl my computer freezes, sometimes more than 2 seconds, but I don't know the reason. It's been happening since Ubuntu 20.04, when I first used this keyboard. The strange fact is that when I use my friend's Dell kb216t keyboard or the integrated keyboard in the laptop, this does not happen.

I don't know if it's a mechanical keyboard (outemu switch) problem or any other thing. I am using Portuguese layout, but it does the same thing when I use English or other layout.

Input keyboard layout:

[image: input keyboard layout]

Comment: Definitely worth trying that keyboard with a different computer if you can - just to confirm it’s not a hardware problem.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. The keyboard has RGB lightnings; sometimes those exceed the limit of USB 2.0 and trigger a blackout. Please be precise about Portuguese layout, tell us what exactly is wrong or not doing, e.g. keys type different such as semicolon instead of cedilla.